# pandas df.plot makes bars with changing width

Tags: pandas, plot, width

I'm using pandas `df.plot` to plot a bar plot and the bars' width is not the same. 
It is also not the same if I specify the width parameter.

My `df` has 19 rows (letters from A to S) and 6 columns (numbers from 1 to 6). I've created a clustered bar plot, 6 bars for each letter.

This is my code:

```
plt.figure()

plot_df.plot(x="Alpha", y=["1", "2", "3","4","5","6"], kind="bar").legend(prop={'size': 7})

plt.ylabel("F1 score")

plt.tight_layout()
```

[what I get is bars with different widths (see the brown or blue bars for instance)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jfvne.png)
[image]

I can't figure out why this is happening, or what can I change. 
thank you!

Comment: Please edit your post, putting your code in a code block and adding your image directly, if possible.

Comment: code formatting, capitalization/punctuation, embed image